# Existe algum problema em omitir o ponto e vírgula em uma tag php com uma expressão apenas

Tags: php

Ao usar php junto com html, sei que funciona omitir o ";" em tags php de uma linha só, mas existe algum problema que isso pode acarretar?

Omitir o ";" é uma boa prática ou não?

```
<?php algumaFuncao() ?>
```

ou

```
<?php algumaFuncao(); ?>
```

**EDIT**

A dúvida é para tags com uma expressão a ser validada apenas, desculpe não especificar isso antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em casos como expressões utilizando a sintaxe alterantiva, eu não utilizo o `;`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php foreach($array as $value) : ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Alguns amigos programadores criticavam a falta de `;` após o `endif`, porém tenho certeza que ninguém usaria um `;` após o fechamento de um `if` comum.

Assim:

```
<?php if  ($x) { ?>

<?php }; ?>
```

Creio que você está se referindo, na sua pergunta, quanto a expressões, como um `echo` simples, ou uma chamada de função.

É altamente recomendável utilizar o `;` nesses casos.

Eu costumo muito olhar o código-fonte de frameworks, para poder tentar melhorar meu padrão de codificação. E observando o código-fonte do `Laravel 4`, pude perceber o que ele faz quando utilizando a sintaxe do Blade.

Exemplo de um código Blade:

```
Meu nome é {{ $nome }} e tenho {{ $idade }} anos
```

O Blade compila o código dessa forma:

```
Meu nome é <?php echo $nome; ?> e tenho <?php echo $idade; ?>
```

Então percebemos que esse framework se preocupou em colocar o `;` ao final da expressão.

Answer (score 0):

Não é obrigatório (nesse caso), porém, é recomendado.

> A tag de fechamento de um bloco de código PHP automaticamente implica
>   em um ponto-e-vírgula; você não precisa ter um ponto-e-vírgula
>   terminando a última linha de um bloco PHP. A tag de fechamento irá
>   incluir uma nova linha logo após, se estiver presente.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Não é necessário nesse caso, pois o `?>` fica encarregado em "finalizar" a linha.

Nesse site http://www.phptherightway.com/, você encontra algumas recomendações e boas práticas.

Answer (score -2):

Após qualquer instrução, é necessário o uso de um ; para que o interpretador reconheça que determinada instrução acaba aí. Após ; o interpretador processa a instrução, exibindo-a na memória do computador e, se não houver erros, passa para a próxima instrução.

### Exemplo:

```
<?php
   echo "Olá como estás?";
   echo "Tudo bem contigo?";
?>
```

ou

```
<?php echo "Olá como estás?"; echo "Tudo bem contigo?" ?>
```

Notem que nesse segundo caso foi retirado a quebra de linhas porque o ponto e vírgula ; é que delimita o comando. E foi retirado o ponto e vírgula ; do último comando porque logo após é fechada a tag do php, não é uma boa prática, porém funciona.

```
<?php echo "Se não usar ponto e vírgula (;) o interpretador irá exibir um erro"; ?>
```

Obs.: Repare bem que o uso de ; no meio texto a ser exibido não afeta a instrução.

> Dados extraídos de:
>   http://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Curso_de_PHP/Sintaxe_b%C3%A1sica

Answer (score -2):

Não é uma boa prática omitir, apesar de funcionar como

```
<?php echo "Assim funciona" ?>
```

Acontece nesse caso, que o compilador vai verificar o que tem logo após o texto, e ele vê que chegou ao fim do bloco PHP, então ele suprime o erro que iria causar e permite ser escrito, porém como bem explicado pelo @Silvio-Andorinha o php exige um `;`

Então sendo assim, seria bom aderir as boas práticas de sempre colocar `;` no fim de suas sentenças em php.

Comment: Olá, obrigado, teria alguma fonte para confirmar sua resposta? para mim é a que melhor explicou, com uma fonte confiável eu posso marcar essa resposta como a melhor.