# É necessário utilizar ponto-e-vírgula no final de uma "expressão única" no PHP?

Tags: php

#### Cenário exemplo:

Vamos supor que tenho uma página que é gerada por includes, e até tem um loop:

```
<? require_once 'classes/classe1.class.php'; ?>

<html>

<head>
    <? include_once 'html/head.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

    <? foreach ($array as $v) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><? echo $v['X'] ?></td>
            <td><? echo $v['Y'] ?></td>
        </tr>

    <? } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

No exemplo, mostro **2 formas** de abrir e fechar o `php` que vejo por aí entre usuários da linguagem. As primeiras finalizam com `;` e as outras não:

```
<? require_once 'classes/classe1.class.php'; ?>
<? include_once 'html/head.php'; ?>
```

e

```
<td><? echo $v['X'] ?></td>
<td><? echo $v['Y'] ?></td>
```

---

#### Dúvidas:

- **Devo ou não fechar** o código mesmo que esteja fechando o trecho ou seria **indiferente**?
- O abrir e fechar do trecho já **é considerado fim de processamento**?
- Isso **poderia interferir** em alguma parte do script?
- É uma **boa prática**?

Comment: Na última linha de um bloco, não é necessário colocar o `;`, mas se tiver uma linha abaixo é necessário.

Comment: Se você não fecha ele vai procurar a instrução a frente no caso é o fechamento do script php que ele interpreta como um end. Não interfere em nada

Comment: Leia na documentação oficial : http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: Acredito não ser uma boa prática, caso você for mexer futuramente no código, pode esquecer de colocar o `;` e causar perca de tempo procurando o problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Existe algum problema em omitir o ponto e vírgula em uma tag php com uma expressão apenas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10082/existe-algum-problema-em-omitir-o-ponto-e-v%c3%adrgula-em-uma-tag-php-com-uma-express)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> **Separação de instruções**
>
> A tag de fechamento de um bloco de código PHP automaticamente implica em um ponto-e-vírgula; você não precisa ter um ponto-e-vírgula terminando a última linha de um bloco PHP. A tag de fechamento do bloco irá incluir uma nova linha logo após, se estiver presente.

Ou seja, a expressão que precede imediatamente o fechamento do bloco PHP não precisa, necessariamente, possuir o ponto-e-virgula.

Só tome cuidado que `<? ?>` é a *short tag* e não é mais recomendada utilizá-la. Prefira sempre `<?php ?>`.

- [Quais vantagens e desvantagens de usar <? ao invés de <?php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205241/5878)
- [Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/5878)

> Devo ou não fechar o código mesmo que esteja fechando o trecho ou seria indiferente?

Para a **última expressão antes do fechamento do bloco PHP**, o uso do ponto-e-vírgula é indiferente. Para todos os outros, <s>existe masterc**d</s> sim, é obrigatório.

> O abrir e fechar do trecho já é considerado fim de processamento?

Sim. O final de bloco, `?>`, já é analisado como final da expressão, por isso o uso do ponto-e-vírgula se torna opcional.

> Isso poderia interferir em alguma parte do script?

Não, em nada.

> É uma boa prática?

Se é indiferente, não tem como ser, ou não, boa prática.

Comment: Então cara, já tinha lido sobre isso `short tag`, então a `<?=` também não ou é padrão?

Comment: @rbz não, a `<?=` não é uma *short tag*. Adicionei links para perguntas que tratam disso.

Comment: Essa short tag está indicando que a saída do script é para enviar para stdout ou seja impressão, é uma abreviação para o echo. <?= (5 + 5) ?> é igual a <?php echo 5+5; ?>

Answer (score 11):

> Devo ou não fechar o código mesmo que esteja fechando o trecho ou seria indiferente?

Não deve nada, apenas pode fechar, se quiser. A *tag* de PHP implica ter um `;` automático sempre no final, e apenas no final. Mas se for pra seguir uma recomendação cega eu diria para colocar.

> O abrir e fechar do trecho já é considerado fim de processamento?

Sim, encerra o código ali. Como PHP é uma linguagem de *script* faz todo sentido ter várias linhas de processamento iniciadas e encerradas dentro do gabarito de HTML. Do ponto de vista sintático cada um é independente. O `;` fica implícito e colocado pelo compilador do PHP.

> Isso poderia interferir em alguma parte do *script*?

Na forma apresentada não. Se tiver mais linhas, a última não precisa, mas as anteriores precisam.

> É uma boa prática?

**Não**. Eu não gosto desse negócio de boa prática, e já disse que tanto faz. Mas gosto de código legível, óbvio, de fácil manutenção (um dia pode ter outra linha ali e terá que ter cuidado). Se o normal é ter o `;` você deve colocar ele sempre, assim mantém uma **consistência**. Não precisamos de boas práticas, precisamos saber os fundamentos e manter a consistência, isto faz código melhor.

**Sim**. Se quiser, pode chamar de boa prática colocar, porque evita confundir-se se precisar colocar mais linhas depois. Evita que uma pessoa que não sabe disto ficar confuso. Evita você olhar para aquilo achar esquisito todas as vezes e desviar o pensamento. Então é útil colocar sempre o `;`, mesmo não sendo necessário.

Boa prática depende de contexto e de ponto de vista, por isso elas são complicadas. As pessoas acham que são receita de bolo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).